# Is it acceptable to leave my company knowing it will damage the company?

Tags: contracts

This week I got a new offer from a previous company I applied to, which offers me the opportunity to start coding less and less, and slowly prepares me for the job I've always wanted. I would want take the job offer (better pay, and more opportunities), but last week, very unexpectedly, a senior announced his leave, which would leave the company with only 1 junior at the end of november if I would hand in my resignation this month as well.

I know it should be purely business, but this will set back the company quite a bit. I work in quite a specialised field, so it will not be easy for them to find replacements (unless you pay a lot) in a short period of time. I feel really bad about it.

What would you do in my situation? Should I turn down the offer for a few months (until they found a new employee) or is it just purely business and just sign the new contract right now?

Comment: In regards to leaves, vacancies, layoffs as well as recruitment - that's entirely the responsibilty of the company. If they can't manage those then it's their problem and definitly not of regular employees. In regards to  _"senior (3,5 years), medior (me, 1 year) and a junior (2 months)"_:  IMO senior is 10y+, medior 5-10y+ and junior is 0-5y - buts thats just my view on dev-experience

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - the way it's written could mislead to a different assumption about what's meant.. ;)

Comment: That senior left and he didn't think about how many would be left. Why should you be thinking about it when a senior didn't?

Answer (score 13):

No - you should not turn down the other offer.

Your job is to look out for yourself. Other people leaving is not your concern. This is entirely the company's problem.

Even the best of companies/employers will fire you if need be. So there is no reason to feel this sorry for them.

Comment: I know that, and if the senior developer hadn't handed in his resignation, I wouldnt even have thought twice about it. But in this case, leaving them in this state... I cant help but feel bad about the whole situation. But you are right, at the end of the day I have to do what is best for me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with feeling bad. However, this not the first nor the last time a company finds itself in this situation. They tend to survive.

Answer (score 4):

> so it will not be easy for them to find replacements (unless you pay a
> lot)

So you are underpaid and still feel bad about leaving ?

The best you can do is to give notice as early as you can so they can start training and looking for a replacement as soon as possible.